# Shortcuts to Networked Locations Disappear

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, domain

I manage the network of a small business and am having a peculiar issue. One of the employees likes to make shortcuts on her desktop to network location. Every couple of weeks or so, the icons disappear.

I haven't actually witnessed the issue, but from what she's told me:

- It happens every couple of weeks
- It only happens to the shortcuts of the networked areas, not the shortcuts to local areas.
- It only happens when she allows the computer to sit idle and then wakes it up from sleep.

I believe that she also gets a dialogue box stating that she's lost connectivity, but I'm not sure about that.

Whenever this happens, she needs to recreate the shortcuts. And finally, out of 25ish computers, hers is the only one that does this.

The workstation runs Windows 7 32 bit and the active directory server is Windows 2008 sp1

The only step I've taken is disallow the computer from shutting off the NIC card to save power.

Any ideas?

Comment: What are the shortcuts pointed at, the UNC path?

Comment: The shortcuts are pointed to individual files and I believe a folder as well. When the employee logs onto this machine, I have a script setup to map a folder ("Files") as a network drive and I'm pretty sure that's where she's added the shortcuts from.

Comment: So the shortcut points to like: "Z:\MyFolder".  Does the mapped drive _also_ disappear when this happens?

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure about that one. But yes, I'm almost positive that the shortcut points to the networked drive.

Comment: That would be the first thing that I check, if the drive mapping is disappearing, then you would first want to solve that; and the shortcut problem is likely to resolve itself.

Comment: Thank you very much, that does make sense and will give me a good head start.

Comment: This could be a result of the maintenance task that Windows runs to delete broken shortcuts. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2642357